# Is there a better tool to visually see Apache Derby tables then the Eclipse DB perspective?

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, derby

I am using the Eclipse Juno Database Development view to view my tables in my Apache Derby  v.10.9.1.0 database.  This works ok. I can see the tables in my Schema in the folders.  I really want to be able to sort my tables results, change values and update without using the SQL scrapbook etc.  I know this sounds crazy but I really liked Oracle SQL developer. I know they don't support Derby.  Is there a better free tool than the Eclipse Database Development perspective? Should I just learn to love sql?

Comment: See here for a list of compatible SQL clients: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby#GUI_Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like SquirrelSQL, which supports schema inspection, sql statement execution, sorting of results, updating, etc.: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There is also dbvisualizer. It's quite nice. If you're running Derby in embedded mode using a program like squirrel dbvis can be problematic though. Because only one JVM can 'mount' the database at a time, which it means either your app or the view app can access it at a time. This gets annoying pretty quickly.

If you're running over the network driver though it's no problem.